# Is there a list of external domains that Sitecore calls as part of normal operating?

Tags: configuration, installation, settings

I'm looking to get a complete list of the URLs that Sitecore calls during normal functionality of the base product. We have a client's IT group that needs to whitelist the outbound external calls to allow them out off their servers/network. There are errors in the logs for some but wondering if there might be more and would rather perform the action once.

Example: [discovery-ces.cloud.sitecore.net](http://discovery-ces.cloud.sitecore.net)

It would be good to have a living document or kb article that showed the version of the software and what external domains are accessed.

#### UPDATE:

Response from support was:

> We have asked our product department for the requested list and have got the following URLs:
>
> - https://discovery-ces.cloud.sitecore.net
> - https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://sdn.sitecore.net/
> - https://apps.sitecore.net/
> - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/help/release/...
> - https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,300,600,700,800
>
> There are a few other components (like Sitecore.Social) that might call:
>
> - http://www.linkedin.com/home
> - https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url
> - http://www.facebook.com/home.php https://plus.google.com
> - https://api.twitter.com/
> - https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.8.0r4/build/yuiloader/yuiloader-min.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Sitecore Installation documentation, I didn't find any specific document which suggest allowing access to any external parties.
With reference to your question, Sitecore offers add on services on top of experience platform, such as Device Detection, GeoIP, Email Delivery and xDB cloud which have their own integration requirements.
Below links will help you to configure your firewalls if you are using any of them.

**Device Detection**
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/device_detection/device_detection/set_up_device_detection

**XDB Cloud**
https://doc.sitecore.net/xdb_cloud/working_with_xdb_cloud/configuring/configure_your_firewall_settings_for_xdb_cloud

**GeoIP Service**
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/ip_geolocation/ip_geolocation/setting_up_sitecore_ip_geolocation

**Email Delivery Service**
https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/configuring_the_delivery_process/message_transfer_agent/set_up_the_message_transfer_agent_mta

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @mohit. I think the device and geoip might do the trick. But I've submitted support ticket to see if Sitecore can provide a definite list and/or KB article as well.

Comment: No worries! @SteveMontgomery. Please update your answer here from Sitecore ticket if there is any further details from Sitecore.

Comment: Updated question with notes from Sitecore support.

Comment: Since their response was missing some of the URLs from the documentation you links you provided I'm leaving this unanswered as it feels like there might be more.